# Lightning Component Bundle Failing on Deployment

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, change-set

I am trying to deploy a changeset that contains a lightning component from a dev sandbox with not much data to a partial sandbox with more data. When I go to validate the inbound changeset with settings as 'default', I get the following errors (they appear to be the same error):

Invalid definition for null:CreateSupportCaseController: null
Invalid definition for null:CreateSupportCaseController: null

My lightning component bundle contains the following: 

**createSupportCase.cmp
createSupportCaseController.js

createSupportCaseController.apxc

createSupportCaseControllerTest.apxc

createSupportCaseHelper.js**

Is there anything wrong with the naming that could be causing the problem?

If I need to include any other information, please let me know. Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the class is failing to deploy for whatever reason. Try deploying them as two change sets, first the classes, then the bundle. Afterwards, consider logging a case with support, because I'm pretty sure we've never had this problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox tried deploying separately and same error. I will log a case. Thanks.

Comment: You can actually create lightning components directly in production. Just make the classes and copy the elements over manually.

Comment: @CasparHarmer nice idea! Could there be any repercussions to doing this?

Comment: Nope, I've done it before with no problems

Comment: @CasparHarmer I have to apologize here. I was under the impression that the test class and the apex class were part of the lightning component bundle. Once I added those to the changeset, the validation worked fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating the component directly in production.

Just make it exactly the same name and copy the helper and controller etc files in one by one in the Developer console.

I've just verified that this works and that the component is valid - it is.

From there, the component should update properly from any updates from the sandbox, as long as the names are an exact match.

---

***Note this only applies to the Lightning Components***

Apex Classes must be deployed normally. If you have a dependency in the Lightning component to the Apex class, you can remove it and then add it back once your have successfully deployed the Apex Class.

---

***Also consider renaming your component*** - Having components and apex classes that are an exact match seems like a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have my domain enabled in your production org.

Activate it and try again.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_reqs_my_domain.htm